# datos definidos por el usuario y clase vector

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa en c++, en el cual uso datos definidos por el usuario y clases vector, sin embargo no se de que manera puedo enviar vectores dinámicos a funciones:

```
struct mascota{ 
char nombre [30];
char especie [30];
char raza [30];
char genero [30];
int edad;
int id;};
struct cliente{
char nombre [30];
char telefono [30];
char direccion [30];
int id;
vector<int>ids;};
```

Esas son los las estructuras que trabajo y trabajo con 2 vectores dinámicos 
pero no como enviarlos a mis funciones de tipo void

```
vector<cliente>clientes;
vector<mascota>mascotas;
#ifndef _ALTAS_H_
#define _ALTAS_H_

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void altas(aquí quiero poner los vectores dinámicos)
{
mascota auxm;
cliente auxc;
```

No pongo todo el código porque es mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu necesitas pasarle un entero a una función, ¿cómo lo haces? Declaras un argumento de tipo `int`:

```
void funcion(int valor);
```

Si en vez de un entero es una cadena de caracteres... entonces pasas un argumento de tipo `char*`:

```
void funcion(char* cadena);
```

Pues con los vectores se hace exactamente igual:

```
void funcion(std::vector<cliente> clientes);
```

Lo único que sucede es que en el caso de objetos grandes (un vector puede contener miles de elmentos), puede ser contraproducente hacer una copia de dicho objeto cada vez que llamamos a la función. En estos casos se suele recurrir al uso de referencias constantes:

```
void funcion(std::vector<cliente> const& clientes);
```

La diferencia entre las dos versiones es que en este último caso no se hace una copia del vector. Una referencia es una suerte de puntero implícito, es decir, copiamos una dirección de memoria en vez de un objeto. Por otro lado, al ser constante se garantiza que el objeto original no se va a ver modificado dentro de la función.

Ahora bien, por el nombre que le has puesto a la función se sobreentiende que la misma va a realizar modificaciones en los objetos... en este caso el `const` sobrará:

```
void funcion(std::vector<cliente> & clientes);
```

Así pues la declaración de tu función podría quedra así:

```
void altas(std::vector<cliente> & clientes, std::vector<mascota> & mascotas);
```

De esta forma tu función recibirá sendas referencias de los vectores, lo que te permitirá modificar los objetos originales.

Answer (score 1):

> No se de que manera puedo enviar vectores dinámicos a funciones.

Tienes problemas de terminología. No sabes el lenguaje en el que estás trabajando: dices que trabajas en [c](/questions/tagged/c) cuando tu código es claramente [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [he editado tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/304976/revisions) para reflejar el lenguaje correcto.

Tampoco pareces tener claro lo que significa "*dinámico*" en el lenguaje. Automático, estático y dinámico son términos que se usan para describir el ciclo de vida de un objeto:

- **Automático**: el objeto se crea dentro de un ámbito y es destruido automáticamente al salir del mismo.

  ```
  void funcion() {
      Objeto o; // El objeto 'o' se crea aquí.
      // …
      // Hacer cosas…
      // …
  } // El objeto 'o' se destruye aquí.
  ```
- **Estático**: el objeto se crea al iniciar el programa<sup>1</sup> y es destruido automáticamente al finalizar el mismo.

  ```
  Objeto o; // El objeto 'o' se crea antes de llamar a 'main'.

  int main() {
      // …
      // Hacer cosas…
      // …
      return 0;
  }

  // El objeto 'o' se destruye después de finalizar 'main.
  ```
- **Dinámico**: el objeto se crea *manualmente* (operador `new`) y debe ser destruido *manualmente* (operador `delete`).

  ```
  void funcion() {
      Objeto *po = new Objeto; // El objeto se crea aquí y se guarda en 'po'.
      // …
      // Hacer cosas…
      // …

      delete po; // El objeto se destruye aquí pidiendo que se borre lo que contiene 'po'.
  }
  ```

Tú no pretendes trabajar con nada dinámico, sólo quieres pasar datos a funciones. Existen tres maneras de pasar un dato a una función:

- **Copia**: copias el dato desde fuera de la función a dentro de la función. Un dato se copia cuando usas como parámetro sólo el nombre del tipo.

  ```
  //           vvvvvv <-- El nombre del tipo.
  void funcion(Objeto copia) {
  //                  ^^^^^ <-- 'copia' será una copia de un objeto de tipo 'Objeto'
      // …
      // Hacer cosas…
      // …
  } // El objeto 'copia' se destruye aquí.

  int main() {
      Objeto dato;
      // Se copia 'dato' dentro de 'funcion'. La copia sólo existe en 'funcion'.
      funcion(dato);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  Cualquier cambio que hagas al objeto copiado, no se reflejará en el objeto original.
- **Referencia**: Pasas un alias al objeto original que a efectos prácticos es exactamente igual al objeto original. Un dato se pasa como referencia cuando añades al tipo un [et](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26) (`&`).

  ```
  //           vvvvvvv <-- El tipo es referencia, tiene un '&'.
  void funcion(Objeto& referencia) {
  //                   ^^^^^^^^^^ <-- 'referencia' será lo mismo que el objeto original.
      // …
      // Hacer cosas…
      // …
  }

  int main() {
      Objeto dato;
      // 'dato' pasa a 'funcion' como referencia.
      funcion(dato);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  Los cambios que hagas sobre la referencia, se aplicarán automáticamente al objeto original.
- **Dirección**: Pasas la dirección de memoria del objeto original, es decir un puntero al dato. Un puntero a dato se crea al añadir al tipo un asterisco (`*`), se obtiene un puntero a un objeto anteponiendo un et a la instancia del objeto.

  ```
  //           vvvvvvv <-- El tipo es un puntero, tiene un '*'.
  void funcion(Objeto* direccion) {
  //                   ^^^^^^^^^ <-- 'direccion' es un puntero.
      // …
      // Hacer cosas…
      // …
  }

  int main() {
      Objeto dato;
      // 'dato' pasa a 'funcion' como puntero.
      funcion(&dato);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  Los cambios que hagas sobre el objeto apuntado por el puntero, se aplicarán automáticamente al objeto original.

Mi propuesta es que redactes tu función `altas` pasando los parámetros que necesites como referencia.

---

<sup>1</sup>Hay matices a esta afirmación, pero no son relevantes para esta pregunta.